# Combine two queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I need help with the union in a single array of two queries :

In a query related absences achievement of students in a quarter :

```
$sSqlAsistencia =
         " SELECT
                ca.idcadete,                    
                coalesce(sum(i.cantidad),0) as cantidad

            FROM 
                cadetes ca,
                cursos c,
                cursos_cadetes cc
                left join inasistencias i on i.fk_idcurso = cc.fk_idcurso and i.fk_idcadete = cc.fk_idcadete
            WHERE 
                c.habilitado = true
                and ca.habilitado = true
                and c.fk_idanolectivo = ".$aAnoLectivoBuscar."
                and c.fk_idano = ".$aAnoBuscar."
                and c.fk_iddivision = ".$aDivisionBuscar."
                and cc.fk_idcurso = c.idcurso
                and cc.fk_idcadete = ca.idcadete
                and (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM i.fecha)  in ".$trimestre ." or i.cantidad is null)

            GROUP BY
                ca.idcadete

            ";
    $sSqlInasistencia = $oDB->Query($sSqlAsistencia);

idcadete | cantidad

203      |    4
305      |    0
120      |    10
```

Then a piece of code I have as a result a student / cadet award for meeting other inquiries:

```
$sSql = " SELECT idcadete, nombre, apellido, matricula
         FROM cadetes
        WHERE idcadete in
        (" . $sSqlPromedioEnCadaMateria . " INTERSECT " . $sSqlPromedioConducta;
        if (strlen($aPromedioGeneralEdFisicaMayorABuscar)) {
          $sSql .= " INTERSECT " . $sSqlPromedioEnEdFisica;
        }


$sSql .=    ")";
    $rsCadetesConPremio=$oDB->query($sSql);

idcadete | nombre | apellido | matricula
203      | adrian | perez    | 212121
```

Try to link the two consultations with INNER JOIN but shoot me wrong , as it should manage to combine both queries like this:

```
$premio = " SELECT a.idcadete, a.nombre, a.apellido, a.matricula, b.cantidad
        FROM ".$rsCadetesConPremio."a inner join ".$sSqlInasistencia."b on a.idcadete = b.idcadete
        ORDER BY a.idcadete";
```

----ERROR-------

I need the following result: $premio

```
idcadete | nombre | apellido | matricula| cantidad
203      | adrian | perez    | 212121   |     4
```

Comment: it is in a different language

Comment: Que es ----ERROR------- ?..

Comment: Thanks, combine both queries in one, on the recommendation in another forum. The code is as follows below......

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to join any two arbitrary queries by wrapping the results of both as derived tables. You will however need to enclose both derived tables in parenthesis : `FROM ( ...) a INNER JOIN ( ...) b`

i.e.:

```
"SELECT a.idcadete, a.nombre, a.apellido, a.matricula, b.cantidad
        FROM (".$rsCadetesConPremio.") a inner join (".$sSqlInasistencia.") b on a.idcadete = b.idcadete
        ORDER BY a.idcadete"
```

Here's a [simplified Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5e57/3).

Comment: Thanks, combine both queries in one, on the recommendation in another forum.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$sSqlAsistencia =
" SELECT
ca.idcadete,
ca.nombre, ca.apellido, ca.matricula
coalesce(sum(i.cantidad),0) as cantidad
FROM
cadetes ca,
cursos c,
cursos_cadetes cc
left join inasistencias i on i.fk_idcurso = cc.fk_idcurso and i.fk_idcadete = cc.fk_idcadete
WHERE
c.habilitado = true
and ca.habilitado = true
and c.fk_idanolectivo = ".$aAnoLectivoBuscar."
and c.fk_idano = ".$aAnoBuscar."
and c.fk_iddivision = ".$aDivisionBuscar."
and cc.fk_idcurso = c.idcurso
and cc.fk_idcadete = ca.idcadete
and (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM i.fecha) in ".$trimestre ." or i.cantidad is null)
and ca.idcadete in (" . $sSqlPromedioEnCadaMateria . " INTERSECT " . $sSqlPromedioConducta;
 
if (strlen($aPromedioGeneralEdFisicaMayorABuscar)) {
$sSqlAsistencia .= " INTERSECT " . $sSqlPromedioEnEdFisica;
}
 
$sSqlAsistencia .= ")
GROUP BY
ca.idcadete
";
```